# Let $A, B, C$, and $D$ be sets with $C \subseteq A$ and $D \subseteq B$. Prove that $D-A \subseteq B-C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I know that in order to prove that $D-A \subseteq B-C$. I need to show that if  ex $ x \in (D-A)$ then $ x \in (B-C)$. Here are a few things I know. If  $ x \in A$ then $ x \in C$ and also if $ x \in B$ then $ x \in D$. I'm not sure how to approach the prove what method I should use to prove it. Can anyone please explain to me how to approach the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Your translation of the hypotheses should be exactly the contrary.

Comment: $B-C=B\cap C^c\supset D\cap C^c\supset D\cap A^c=D-A$, where the first inclusion is due to $B\supset D$ and the second due to $A\supset C$, which implies that $C^c\supset A^c$.

Comment: When you write "I need to show that there exist $x\in(D-A)$ and $x\in(B-C)$," you seem to be confused as to what you need to show.  Instead of a "there exist," you need to show that **if** $x\in(D-A)$, **then** $x\in(B-C)$. That, after all, is what it means for $D-A$ to be a subset of $B-C$.

Comment: @BarryCipra I see what you mean I will edit my question. Thank you.

Comment: @jeffc, you're welcome. However, the next sentence ("If $x\in A$ then $x\in C$...") has the if/then's backwards. (Sorry I didn't include that in my first comment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following statement:

I know. If $x∈A$ then $ x∈C$ and also if $x∈B$ then $x∈D.$

Should have been:

I know. If $x∈C$ then $x∈A$ and also if $x∈D$ then $x∈B.$

Back to $$ D-A \subseteq B-C$$

If $ x $ is in $D-A$,then $x$ is in  $D$ and not  in $A$.

Thus  $x$ is in $B$ and not in$ C$.

That is, $x$ is in $B-C.$

Answer (score 0):

Your way to write things is wrong: you have to prove that *for all* $x\in D\setminus A$, one has $x\in A\setminus C$.

So take any such $x$: it belongs to $D$, but not to $A$. As it belongs to $D$, it belongs to $B$ by hypothesis. And as it is *not* in $A$, it can't be in $C$ since $A$ contains  $C$. Thus, $x$ lies in $B\setminus C$.

Comment: @BarryCipra: Yes. I have some some addiction to *lapsus  calami* when I post  late :o). 'Tis fixed. Thanks for pointing it!